# Why using echo, unnecessary string length's number also include in message?

Tags: php, string, echo, fwrite

I wrote a simple PHP script to unzip all .zip files, and just print out message if the process is fail or success. But I got this weird message with string length number including in it.

It's not the big deal, the script still working but I wonder why this happen. This happened even when I just write texts to log file, and without echo anything to browser (line 15). The texts in log file are ok. Could anyone help me? I'm a newbie.

Thanks

```
<?php

$zip = new ZipArchive;
$destdir = getcwd();
$t = time();
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Saigon');
$date = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', time());

foreach (glob("*.zip") as $zipfilename) {

    if ($zip->open($zipfilename) === True) {

    $zip->extractTo($destdir);
    $zip->close();
    echo "Unpack file at " .$date. " in " .$destdir. ". File name : " . $zipfilename . " successfully </br>";

    /*Write status of unpacking process to log file */

    $logfile = fopen("unpack log.txt", "a");
    echo fwrite($logfile, "Unpack file at ".$date." in ".$destdir.". File name : ". $zipfilename." successfully"."\n");
    fclose($logfile);

    }

    else {

    $logfile = fopen("unpack log.txt", "a");
    echo fwrite($logfile, "Unpack file at ".$date." in ".$destdir.". File name : ". $zipfilename." failed");
    fclose($logfile);

    }
 }

?>
```

> Unpack file at 21/05/2015 23:10:18 in {dir}. File name : 2.zip successfully 
>   119
>   Unpack file at 21/05/2015 23:10:18 in {dir}. File name : 3.zip successfully 
>   119

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

fwrite() returns the number of bytes written, or FALSE on error.

You are echoing the return of fwrite which is why it is showing the bytes written